# CSS selector to target all elements that are not descendants of class name?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Codepen example is [here](https://codepen.io/tmrczk/pen/xNNwGr).

**Question**. How do I paint yellow all inputs that are NOT descendants of `div.b`?

My attempt paints all three elements yellow:

```
:not(.b) input.myInp {background:yellow}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
:not(.b) > div > p input.myInp {background:yellow}
```

You need to make the selector specific enough that it does not match with the parent .a element.

Comment: What to do in the case when input.myInp lives deeper or on a different path altogether?

Comment: Ideally I would say you may want to consider making a stand alone class that applies the yellow effect, and put it on the input themselves, so you control exactly which ones are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not working because you're targeting **any** element that does not have the class `.b` but has an `<input>` descendant, and since the input has two ancestor elements which don't have this class the rule applies to them as well.

You should just specify that you're referring to the container's themselves by including the parent in your selector:

```
div.a > :not(.b) input.myInp {background:yellow}
```

Comment: That does not work if I nest .b in another div - look at updated codepen.